# Анимация с radiobutton. Смена фона по клику

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, transition

Нужно сделать такую переключалку на чистом css, без js 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот что у меня получилось. А как сделать чтобы кружок так же переползал и такую же смену фону как на гифке?

```css
.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.check {
  position: relative;
}

.radio {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}

.radio+.label {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 0 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.radio+.label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: transparent;
}

.radio+.label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 5px;
  width: 29px;
  height: 29px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s;
}

.radio:checked+.label:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.panel {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 500px;
  top: -241px;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: width 1s;
}

.radio--1:checked~.panel {
  background: #9A59B5;
  width: 500px;
  left: -175px;
}

.radio--2:checked~.panel {
  background: #3598DB;
  width: 500px;
  left: -224px;
}

.radio--3:checked~.panel {
  background: #1BBC9B;
  width: 500px;
  left: -274px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Check</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="check">
      <input class="radio radio--1" id="radio1" name="change-color" checked type="radio">
      <label class="label" for="radio1"></label>
      <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="check">
      <input class="radio radio--2" id="radio2" name="change-color" type="radio">
      <label class="label" for="radio2"></label>
      <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="check">
      <input class="radio radio--3" id="radio3" name="change-color" type="radio">
      <label class="label" for="radio3"></label>
      <div class="panel"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Совсем неправильно к вопросу подошли. Тут у вас должен быть некий viewport, окошко, в котором нужно показать слайд соответствующей нажатому radiobutton. А сам фон из трех слайдов является единым целым. Двигать его нужно либо через transform: translate, либо через background-position.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
:root {
  --basesize: 200px;
  --animationspeed: .3s;
}

.viewport {
  width: var(--basesize);
  height: var(--basesize);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.bg {
  width: calc(var(--basesize) * 3);
  height: var(--basesize);
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, darkorchid 33.33333333%, dodgerblue 33.33333333%, dodgerblue 66.66666666%, darkturquoise 66.66666666%);
  transition: var(--animationspeed);
}

#first:checked~.bg {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

#second:checked~.bg {
  transform: translateX(calc(-1 * var(--basesize)));
}

#third:checked~.bg {
  transform: translateX(calc(-2 * var(--basesize)));
}

.controls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: var(--basesize);
  height: var(--basesize);
  display: flex;
  z-index: 100;
}

.controls-wrapper {
  margin: auto;
}

.controls-wrapper label {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: calc(var(--basesize) / 10);
  height: calc(var(--basesize) / 10);
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.controls-wrapper {
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle, white 22%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 22%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: calc((-1 * var(--basesize) / 10)) -2px;
  transition: var(--animationspeed);
}

#first:checked~.controls .controls-wrapper {
  background-position: calc((-1 * var(--basesize) / 10)) -2px;
}

#second:checked~.controls .controls-wrapper {
  background-position: 0 -2px;
}

#third:checked~.controls .controls-wrapper {
  background-position: calc(var(--basesize) / 10) -2px;
}

.viewport input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="viewport">
  <input type="radio" name="slide" id="first" checkhed>
  <input type="radio" name="slide" id="second">
  <input type="radio" name="slide" id="third">
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="controls-wrapper">
      <label for="first"></label><label for="second"></label><label for="third"></label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bg">
  </div>
</div>
```